# Is CNN with Avg pooling and ReLU an odd function?

Tags: function, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

For each input x, we get output h(x,Para) from CNN, where h is the CNN and Para is a concatenation of all CNN parameters.

Then I'm curious if h is an odd function or not, i.e. if h(x,Para)=-h(-x,Para), in most of the modern CNN architecture such a VGG or ResNet?

If not, is it possible to make it an odd function?

Comment: Can you make it more clear? I don't understand your post

Comment: Given an input image X=[r,g,b], where r=red, g=green and b=blue. Convolutional neural network will output an result Y. If I feed another input -X=[-r,-g,-b] into the network, will CNN output  -Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
Generally speaking, Neural network `approximate` function. Its weights change when your data change, which mean NN is not a fixed function. You can imagine that way: NN is not `3x + y - 5 = 0` but it is `ax + by + c = 0`, and you will learn the `a, b, c` which are best fit the data.
Your question is just wrong.
And yes, we can made it **approximate** and odd function (by providing corresponding data)